# Running node.js on web matrix and IIS

Tags: node.js, webmatrix

I am trying to teach myself node.js.

I have installed node and it works from the command line.

I am now trying to use web matrix 3 as the IDE for node.

I have been doing the following steps

1. Creating a new site using the template gallery.
2. I choose empty node.js website.
3. I create a js file and write some code
4. I run it on chrome or firefox.

When I create a new project, a file, server.js is automatically created with the following code:

```
    var http = require('http');
    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
        res.end('Hello, world!');
    }).listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

Whenever I try running a file, I get an url like "http://localhost:39540/" on the browser and server.js is executed.

I can understand the above code and if I delete server.js, I get an error.

Whatever file I try to run, server.js gets executed.

even if I try a simple console.log,, server.js gets executed.

Probably I have to change something in the config.web file?

How can I run my files using web matrix and IIS instead of server.js? (Like I can run on cloud 9 IDE)

I apologize in advance if this question sounds stupid or this is not the correct forum.